# Problems parenting an armature to a mesh

Tags: mesh, armature, bones

I have an armature that I am trying to parent to a mesh and it isn't working. See the image below for reference. I am just a beginner, so feel free to ask me questions as I am not sure why it is acting this way.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Select the armature first and then select the mesh.
Afterwards parent the objects <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> and try *Automatic Weights*

Comment: all the videos i have watched have said the opposite trying now

Comment: update it is now parented correctly but is still acting the same. also there is no option for automatic weights if you want to talk i can give a discord link or something.

Comment: https://discord.gg/nEmqPNf